# Script lanzado desde regla udev se queda zombie al lanzar un nuevo proceso

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy intentando usar una regla udev para lanzar un cliente dbus desde un script.

La regla udev saltará cuando se conecte un pendrive, y ejecuta el script `usbdevinserted.sh`, el cual copiara el identificador del pendrive a un fichero y lanzará el cliente dbus

La regla udev es esta:

```
 KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/usbdevinserted.sh"
```

El código de `usbdevinserted.sh` este:

```
set 2>&1 | grep DEVPATH | cut -d "=" -f 2 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo

#Get list of users with graphic session started, and their active display 
userdisplay=$(who | gawk '/\(:[[:digit:]](\.[[:digit:]])?\)/ { print $1 ";" substr($NF, 2, length($NF)-2) }' | uniq)

#for each user, show notification and (only in polkit >= 106) launch dbus client 
for element in $userdisplay
do          
    #get username       
    user=$(echo $element | cut -d ";" -f 1)

    #get display active of this user        
    export DISPLAY=$(echo $element | cut -d ";" -f 2)

    #Send notification to user
    su $user -c 'notify-send "Pendrive Reminder" "Shutdown lock enabled. The shutdown will be unlocked when pendrive is disconnected"'
    #if polkit version >=106, also launch dbus client
    if test $polkit_version -ge 106
    then
        su $user -c 'python /usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py' &
    fi
done
```

Y el cliente dbus (`client.py`) es este:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Notify
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

dbus_loop = DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SystemBus(mainloop=dbus_loop)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def msg_handler(*args,**keywords):
    try:
        #show notification to desktop
        Notify.init('Pendrive Reminder')
        notify = Notify.Notification.new('Pendrive Reminder', 'Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown')
        notify.show()
    except:
        pass

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler_function=msg_handler, dbus_interface='org.preminder', path_keyword='path')
loop.run()
```

La idea es que el script (`usbdevinserted.sh`) termine, dejando al cliente dbus en ejecución.
He probado lanzándolo manualmente desde la terminal, y funciona bien: el script finaliza y deja al cliente dbus en ejecución.

Pero, cuando lanzo el script desde la regla udev, el script, aún habiendo ejecutado su secuencia de instrucciones, se queda zombie y no muere hasta pasados unos minutos, tiempo en el cual deja udev bloqueado.

Y, si lanzo el script desde udev, quitando la parte en que se lanza el cliente dbus (`client.py`), el script finaliza correctamente sin quedarse zombie.

¿sabéis donde puede estar el problema?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Tal como me han indicado en los comentarios, he probado con:

```
su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py &>/dev/null' & | at now
```

Pero ahora el cliente dbus no se llega a lanzar (o muere junto al script)
También he probado con:

```
su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py &>/dev/null' & - batch
```

Pero el script no llega a finalizar (ni tan siquiera como zombie)

Y con:

```
su $user -c '/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py &>/dev/null' & - at
```

el script se vuelve a quedar zombie hasta unos minutos despues

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir regla udev?

Comment: Udev es un subsistema de GNU/Linux, encargado de capturar y responder a eventos de entrada/salida provenientes de dispositivos. 

En este caso, lo estoy usando para capturar el evento de conexión de un pendrive, copiar su identificador a un fichero, y lanzar el cliente dbus

Comment: En [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) mencionan que _udev does not run these programs on any active terminal, and it does not execute them under the context of a shell. Be sure to ensure your program is marked executable, if it is a shell script ensure it starts with an appropriate shebang (e.g. #!/bin/sh), and do not expect any standard output to appear on your terminal_. No veo el shebang aquí. ¿Es ejecutable? ¿Has puesto "prints" o "prints" a archivo para ver hasta dónde llega el script?

Comment: tal vez se deba a que via udev el script es un hijo que al morir el padre deja de existir. prueba este hilo https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56243/how-to-run-long-time-process-on-udev-event

Comment: @aloMalbarez gracias! lo mirare!

Comment: @aloMalbarez he actualizado la pregunta

Comment: prueba crear un job para at y llamar directo al at el pipe si mal no recuerdo ejecuta el programa y le pasa el out al at.   $ at -f eljob now   eljob es un archivo con lista de comandos

Comment: @aloMalbarez
entonces ¿tendré que crear otro nuevo script con los comandos que necesito ejecutar?

Comment: no tengo disponible un shell ahora pero segun recuerdo es un archivo de texto que contiene el comando tal cual lo ejecutarías ej /usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py &>/dev/null

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75357/discussion-between-alo-malbarez-and-almuhs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado:

He creado un fichero, con los comandos que debo lanzar, y lo he lanzado con `at -f fichero`

El script queda así:

```
set 2>&1 | grep DEVPATH | cut -d "=" -f 2 >> /tmp/usbdevinfo

#Get list of users with graphic session started, and their active display 
userdisplay=$(who | gawk '/\(:[[:digit:]](\.[[:digit:]])?\)/ { print $1 ";" substr($NF, 2, length($NF)-2) }' | uniq) 


#Get polkit version
polkit_version=$(pkaction --version | cut -d " " -f 3 | cut -d "." -f 2)

#for each user, show notification and (only in polkit >= 106) launch dbus client 
for element in $userdisplay
do          
    #get username       
    user=$(echo $element | cut -d ";" -f 1)

    #get display active of this user        
    export DISPLAY=$(echo $element | cut -d ";" -f 2)

    #Send notification to user
    su $user -c 'notify-send "Pendrive Reminder" "Shutdown lock enabled. The shutdown will be unlocked when pendrive is disconnected"'

    #if polkit version >=106, also launch dbus client
    if test $polkit_version -ge 106
    then
        #To avoid udev lock after launch dbus client, launch client as task

        #Creates a temporally file, with commands to launch in the task 
        echo "export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" > at_task        
        echo "/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/client.py" >> at_task                      

        #Launch task with at command
        su $user -c 'at -f at_task now'
    fi
done
```

Gracias @aloMalbarez !!